How to set up encryption in direct messages from dart matrix bot?
i use the https://github.com/famedly/matrix-dart-sdk with quite opaque documentation (at least for me)...
i am writing a bridge between a home appliance and matrix.
I managed to set up the system to communicate with non encrypted rooms.
Now i want to be able to respond to direct messages. I managed to respond to the invitation to a direct chat, and join the room, but now the responses are not intelligible, lacking proper encryption.....
my project is a dart project, adding flutter libraries seems not proper to me.
I found a olm library, also from famedly, but lacking documentation too...
is there any example out there on how to activate that olm in a dart project, and how to send encrypted messages back?
i checked with what i found in the code (also taking into account what was suggested in the comment), it should activate:
final libcrypto =DynamicLibrary.open('libcrypto.so.3');
print("crypto lib: $libcrypto");
await olm.init();
print("inst olm ${olm.get_library_version()}");

client = Client('IpxBot');
print("++++++++ encryption enables: ${client.encryption}");

gives:
crypto lib: DynamicLibrary: handle=0x7b233c0015d0
inst olm [3, 2, 13]
++++++++ encryption enabled: null

so loading of libcrypto is a success, creating an olm object, also, but the client still starts without any sort of encryption?
i didn't find in the client CTOR an indication of any olm starter object...
unfortunately there is no discussion forum activated on the project, and when submitting an issue there is mention of a chat, but no reference where that chat might be....
---Edit:
Following the example, i changed the call to create the matrix object to :
 client = Client('IpxBot',
        databaseBuilder: (client) async{
      final Directory dir = Directory(dbdir);
      final db = HiveCollectionsDatabase("bot_chat", dir.path);
      await db.open();

      return db;
    }


and this activated the encryption for the bot...
but now i have a potential disk leak in the form of the database for the bot....
there is even less documentation for that HiveCollectionsDatabase than for the matrix client....
so how do i make the bot forget everything and purge the database every hour?

You shouldn't need those flutter packages in pure Dart. They are just an easy way to install libcrypto. That's used (via FFI) and you can see where it tries to load it from here: https://github.com/famedly/matrix-dart-sdk/blob/main/lib/src/utils/crypto/ffi.dart - it varies depending on the underlying platform.

that's what it seemed to me, so i added a test for the crypto lib:
final libcrypto =DynamicLibrary.open('libcrypto.so.3');
    print("crypto lib: $libcrypto");
    await olm.init();
    print("inst olm ${olm.get_library_version()}");
    client = Client('IpxBot');
    print("encryption enabled: ${client.encryption}");```
which gives as output:

crypto lib: DynamicLibrary: handle=0x7b233c0015d0
inst olm [3, 2, 13]
encryption enabled: null
so, libcrypto is ok, olm is ok, still no encryption?
